# Transform rotate and translate of circle img inside another img

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to animate a sun with the outer rays slowly rotating. I have two images: sun_inner and sun_outer. I use absolute positioning and transform:translate to center the inner sun within the container. However, when I try to rotate the inner sun (which has a smiley face) a few degrees it is not rotating along the center axis, and the inner sun is moving up and down.

Any help in getting the rotation of the inner sun to be centered within the container is appreciated!

As an example here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4mcdLcus/

```css
.sun-inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  /*
  In the animation I apply translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) 
  to keep the inner circle centered, which is not working. 
  If I have translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) without the rotation 
  it is centered properly
  */
  animation-name: sun_inner_rotate;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.sun-inner img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
.sun-outer {
  animation-name: sun_outer_rotate;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.sun-outer img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
@keyframes sunrise {
  0% {
    bottom: -130vh;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes sun_inner_rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    ;
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotate(12deg) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
  66% {
    transform: rotate(-26deg) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(10deg) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
}
@keyframes sun_outer_rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
.sunContainer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-name: sunrise;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sunContainer">
  <div class="sun-inner">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Compass_360_%28en%29.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="sun-outer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Compass_360_%28en%29.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Harry - yes it works, thanks for helping explain transform-origin, that was the missing piece! https://jsfiddle.net/mxf3jkxt/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to use two animations or do anything additional to the `@keyframes` that is already configured. All that is required is to only set the `transform-origin` properly for the inner element.

The inner element is originally positioned at `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` of the parent element (which in other words means that the top left of the inner element is at the center point of the parent). Afterwards it is vertically and horizontally centered using `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)` trick.

So, when you rotate the element the `transform-origin` should be set as `left top` for the element to rotate around the center point of the parent. Only then it will remain perfectly centered.

```css
.sun-inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  animation-name: sun_inner_rotate;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-origin: left top;  /* note the change */
}
.sun-inner img, .sun-outer img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.sun-outer {
  animation-name: sun_outer_rotate;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
@keyframes sunrise {
  0% {
    bottom: -130vh;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes sun_inner_rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotate(12deg) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
  66% {
    transform: rotate(-26deg) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(10deg) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  }
}
@keyframes sun_outer_rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
.sunContainer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-name: sunrise;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sunContainer">
  <div class="sun-inner">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Compass_360_%28en%29.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="sun-outer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Compass_360_%28en%29.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternately, you can invert the order in which the transforms are applied on the element. You can apply the `rotate` first on the element and then apply `translateX` and `translateY` on the rotated element. This will also keep it perfectly centered. (When multiple transforms are specified, the first one from the right is always executed first and the last one from right is always executed last).

```css
.sun-inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  animation-name: sun_inner_rotate;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.sun-inner img, .sun-outer img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.sun-outer {
  animation-name: sun_outer_rotate;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
@keyframes sunrise {
  0% {
    bottom: -130vh;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes sun_inner_rotate { /* note the change to the order */
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  33% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(12deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(-26deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(10deg);
  }
}
@keyframes sun_outer_rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
.sunContainer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-name: sunrise;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sunContainer">
  <div class="sun-inner">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Compass_360_%28en%29.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="sun-outer">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Compass_360_%28en%29.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the transform origin change worked, however it looks like it is 1 px off in comparison to the second technique you showed (jsfiddle below). Thanks again for the answer!! https://jsfiddle.net/b95k146n/6/

Comment: That's interesting @RonI. For me the output of both the snippets look the same. Do you see the issue in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxf3jkxt/2/) also? Maybe there are some browser issues. I am using Chrome v53.0 dev-m.

Comment: That fiddle looks good and I see you used transform-origin. This is the fiddle I was referring to (1 px off). I took a screenshot of both and blew them up in photoshop to verify, and it is 1px lower than the other. However, I can't add a screenshot in a comment.

Comment: @RonI: I am on a tight schedule for the next few days. I'll have a look at it during the weekend and let you know. By the way did you miss to add the fiddle link in your comment?

Comment: @RonI: I just had a quick look and you haven't moved the `height` and `width` from the `.sun-inner img` to `.sun-inner` like in my fiddle. This misalignment was exactly the reason why I did that change. The reason for misalignment is because the `.sun-inner` has no fixed height/width, it expands to fit the `img` and for some strange reason it's dimensions become 150 x 154 (you can check this in Dev console). This 4px extra in height is the reason for misalignment.